# React-Native Button onPress doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with `onPress`, tried all the solutions and did not work `handleClick` function,
I've tried it with following approaches as well:

```
onPress={this.handleClick}
onPress={this.handleClick()}
onPress={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
onPress={() => this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

And I tried to change the function to:

```
handleClick(){
   console.log('Button clicked!');
}
```

and this is the my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import Card from './common/Card';
import CardItem from './common/CardItem';
import Buttom from './common/Buttom';
import Input from './common/Input';

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    }
  }

  onLoginPress() {
    //console.log(`Email is : ${ this.state.email }`);
    //console.log(`Password is : ${ this.state.password }`);
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Card>

          <CardItem>
              <Input
                  label='Email'
                  placeholder='Enter your email'
                  secureTextEntry={false}
                  onChangeText = { (email) => this.setState({ email })}
              />
          </CardItem>

          <CardItem>
              <Input
                  label='Password'
                  placeholder='Enter your password'
                  secureTextEntry={true}
                  onChangeText = { (password) => this.setState({ password })}
              />
          </CardItem>

          <CardItem>
            <Buttom onPress={this.handleClick}> Login </Buttom>
          </CardItem>

        </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my Buttom.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

const Buttom = (props) => {
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.ButtomView} >
      <Text style={styles.TextButtom}> {props.children} </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ButtomView: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 35,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#2a3744',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginVertical: 15
  },
  TextButtom: {
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 15,
  }
});
export default Buttom;
```

Comment: You need to provide how your `Buttom` component looks like, because you are just passing `onPress` props to it. And that is probably the reason behind this problem.

Comment: i'm edit the question and added the Buttom component ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not bind event to `Component`. Event is only can attached to React Native element in React-Native or DOM in React only.

You should pass event handler,

```
<Buttom onPressHanlder={this.handleClick}> Login </Buttom>
```

In `Buttom` component use `props.onPressHanlder` to call passed event handler :

```
const Buttom = (props) => {
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.ButtomView} onPress={props.onPressHanlder}>
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

      <Text style={styles.TextButtom}> {props.children} </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bind the function to scope

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
```

Them `<Buttom onPress={() => this.handleClick() }> Login </Buttom>`

Comment: no need to bind it if you use arrow function inside the onPress

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart the app after adding new packages.

(using `react-native start` or `react-native run-android`)